# How to loop through variable names using freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

I have a few variables that i passed from Java to FTL file.
e.g. variable1, variable2, variable 3

How can i retrieve the value for these variables using a loop?
Below is the sample code. It is not working correctly though.

```
<#assign x=3>
<#list 1..x as i>
  ${abc+1}
</#list>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic variable names can be used through special hash variable `.var` (and `.data_model`) combined with the `[]` operator:

```
<#assign x=3>
<#list 1..x as i>
  ${.vars['abc'+ i?c]}
</#list>
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, it worked like this:

```
<#assign x=3>
<#list 1..x as i>
     variable_name:${.vars['variable'+i]}
</#list>
```

Output:

variable_name: (value of variable1)
variable_name: (value of variable2)
variable_name: (value of variable3)

If you just want to print variable1, variable2, variable3

```
<#assign x=3>
<#list 1..x as i>
     ${'variable'+i}
</#list>
```

Output:
variable1
variable2
variable3